# How to use PHP alert box

Tags: php

I have a html page, a textbox(Required field) and a button and a php script associated with the button for sending an email

Whenever i put my email address and clicks on button it is sending mail, all are working fine but i want whenever anyone give his/her email id and clicks the butto a alert box will come with a message thanks for subscribing us.

how to do it .??

this is my html

```
Subscribe us</p>
          <form id="subscribe" name="subscribe" action="subscribe.php" method="post"
 class="validate" target="_blank">
            <div class="input-append">
              <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" />
              <button class="subscribe-button btn" type="submit" onclick="return
    check();">SUBSCRIBE</button>
            </div>
          </form>
```

and this is my php script

```
<?php
/* subject and email varialbles*/

$emailSbuject = 'Subscribe';
$webMaster = 'help@intaxfin.com';
$emailSbuject2 = 'Thank you';
$client = ' $emailFeild\r\n';
/*gathering data variables*/

$emailFeild = $_POST['email'];

// admin message body
$body= <<<EOD
Our new subscriber is $emailFeild

Email: $emailFeild 
EOD;

$textMessage = <<<EOD

    Thank you for subscribing us. Somebody will get back to you as soon as possible.

EOD;
    $headers = "From: $emailFeild\r\n";
    $header = "From: $noreply@intaxfin.com";
    $success = mail($webMaster,$emailSbuject,$body,$headers);
    $success1 = @mail($emailFeild,$emailSbuject2,$textMessage,$header);
    /*Result*/


    $theResults = <<<EOD
EOD;

echo  "$theResults";

header("Location: http://www.sample.com/");
exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simple you can put a javascript code in php.

**Replace this:**

```
header("Location: http://www.sample.com/");
```

**with this:**

```
echo "<script>alert('Thanks you for subscribing!')</script>";
```

**Please note:**

To be honest you better re-direct the user to another page in order to avoid the user re-submitting the page on a refresh. Have a look at [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) Pattern.

Popups can be extremely annoying on websites. You should create a page called "thank-you.html" that you can re-direct the user to on successful submission which has access to the site navigation options or even just do a re-direct back to the form page after a few seconds.

Comment: Thank you so much @parag. i was looking for this only. :D

Answer (score 1):

Why not try to put alert box in your javascript function check() before any server part (ajax call, redirect or whatever you do)?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `header("Location: http://www.sample.com/");` with an HTML document that includes the message you want, formatted the way you want.